# How to write any(diff(vec) < 0) as a pipe?

Tags: r, pipe, magrittr

I have a vector vec like this `vec <- c(1,4,5)` and I want to check whether there are any steps down in the vector. I do this using:

```
any(diff(vec) < 0)
# [1] FALSE
```

No steps down. Okay. But when I try to use this code in a pipe I get a TRUE and an warning:

```
library(magrittr)
vec %>% diff() %>% any(. < 0)
# [1] TRUE
# Warning message:
# In any(., . < 0) : coercing argument of type 'double' to logical
```

How to correctly write `any(diff(vec) < 0)` as a pipe?

Comment: See: [What are the differences and use cases of the five Magrittr Pipes %>%, %<>%, %$%, %!>% and %T>%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76326742) at *When dot is nested, lhs is still placed first*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of solutions already, but no explanation.  The reason your original didn't work is that `magrittr` pipes treat `.` differently when it is in a nested function call.

By nested function call, I mean that `.` is not an argument to the function that is the target of the pipe.  In `any(. < 0)`, that function is `any()`, and its argument is `. < 0`, which is actually a function call to the `<` function.  So the `.` is in a "nested function call".

If `.` is only in a nested function call, it is implicitly used as the first argument as well, so the code

```
x %>% any(. < 0)
```

is treated as

```
any(x, x < 0)
```

To suppress this weird behaviour, put the expression in braces, i.e. your example would be

```
vec %>% diff() %>% { any(. < 0) }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "nested function call" here? This seems to be the actual point that made troubles in my code..

Comment: I've added some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
vec %>%
    diff() %>%
    `<`(0) %>%
    any()
```

or

```
vec %>%
    diff() %>%
    {
        . < 0
    } %>%
    any()
```

or

```
vec %>%
    {
        any(diff(.) < 0)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

using magrittr pipes:

```
vec %>% diff() %>% `<`(0) %>% any()
[1] FALSE
```

Using base pipes:

```
vec |> diff() |> {\(x)x < 0}() |> any()
[1] FALSE
```

See here for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72474832/16730940

Answer (score 1):

*Base*

```
vec |> diff() |> base::`<`(0) |> any()
# [1] FALSE
```

*magrittr*

```
library(magrittr)

vec %>% diff %>% `<`(0) %>% any
# [1] FALSE
```

or, as suggested by *@MrFlick*

```
library(magrittr)

vec %>% diff %>% is_less_than(0) %>% any
# [1] FALSE
```

---

*Data:*

```
vec <- c(1, 4, 5)
```

Comment: If you import all of `magrittr`, might as well use `vec %>% diff %>% is_less_than(0) %>% any` to make things clearer.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for sharing your magrittr knowledge, I've included it!